# concat multiple strings

Tags: sql, concatenation

How to combine multiple strings?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you mean by 'combine' multiple strings?   Under what context did you want to combine strings?

Comment: It would depend on the specific database. The standard form is `expr1 || expr2`, but many databases use `CONCAT(expr1, expr2)`.

Comment: Under what kind of RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Add two or more strings together CONCAT function of sql syntax:

```
    CONCAT(string1, string2, ...., string_n)
```

For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Welcome','to','sql');
```